# Header dinamico dependiendo el producto | Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7

tengo un catalogo de productos en Angular 7 y me gustaría que en cada producto el header cambiara para que tenga los meta data de URL, Title, Image etc... diferente para cada producto, esto como se puede hacer?

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya lo he conseguido solucionar dejo la solución aquí.

**CAMBIAR LOS META TAGS**

1). Importamos en el componente que queremos actualizar los meta el siguiente modulo

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

2). Lo declaramos en el constructor.

```
private _metaService: Meta
```

3). En el ngOnInit declaramos el contenido de los metas.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._metaService.addTags([
      {name: 'description', content: 'How to use Angular 4 meta service'},
      {name: 'author', content: 'talkingdotnet'},
      {name: 'keywords', content: 'Angular, Meta Service'}
    ]);
  }
```

Información mas extensa aquí: [VER MÁS](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-set-html-meta-tags-using-angular-4/)

**CAMBAIR EL TITULO DE LA PAGINA**

1). Importamos el modulo en el componentes donde queremos cambiar el title.

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

2). Lo declaramos en el constructor.

```
private _titleService: Title,
```

3). En el ngOnInit declaramos el contenido del title.

```
this._titleService.setTitle('Estamos en la pagina del producto');
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Si que se puede, añade estos imports a tu código.

```
import { Title, Meta }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Declaramos en el constructor las clases:

```
constructor(private meta: Meta,private title: Title) { }
```

Luego modificas el titulo y la etiqueta meta en alguna función:

```
this.title.setTitle( "Emplo titulo 1");
this.meta.addTag({ name: 'description', content: 'How to use Angular 4 meta' });
this.meta.addTag({ name: 'author', content: 'talkingdotnet' });
this.meta.addTag({ name: 'keywords', content: 'Angular, Meta Service' });
```

Aquí dejo alguno enlaces con las información:
https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title
https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta#addtag

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda ya lo solución y también puse la solución arriba yo también jejeje, gracias igualmente crack!!!